# TinyMCE 3.4.7 <td > <tr > tags breaking and shown as string not table data

Tags: html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have an HTML file which has been created by MS Word and then cleaned using HTML Tidy. The file is already uploaded on server and opens correctly in browser. On client request this file will be automatically loaded in TINY interface for editing. Up to now with Tiny version 3.9.3 everything was fine. Issue started when I upgraded to Tiny version 3.4.7. Now after loading file in the editor instance of Tiny, I can see some garbage like `<td >`, `<tr >` which is resulting in breaking table formatting. If I check the html source of the document in Tiny then I found that `<td >` tag has been replaced by `&lt;td &gt;` and similarly for `<tr >`. My original html file which has been passed through TIDY and stored in server has also a space before closing the tag (something like `<td >` `<tr >`).  This is due to the fact that TIDY has not cleaned it correctly.

Now my problem is that till Tiny version 3.9.3, the tag like `<td >` is treated like `<td>` and my editor instance was not breaking the table and hence no garbage. But with new version 3.4.7 (also with 3.4.8 released on 2/2/2012) I am facing the issue and getting `<td >` `<tr >` in editor instance and breaking table formatting. My problem is that now I can't change the server file, so I need help to fix this without manual editing of document. Is there any way to tell TinyMCE to treat `<td >` as html tags as it was doing in earlier versions? and what has been changed in TinyMCE in table handling?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex issue. With the jump to version 4.x there is a functional cleanup system involved. You may hava a look at the tinymce init params [valid_element](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements)s and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children).
There is a default config active, but you may need to create your own one.

Another option could be to deactivate cleanup setting the tinymce init cleanup parameter to false:

```
cleanup: false,
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will look and will share my findings

Answer (score 0):

As per [Tiny Bug tracker](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5002) issue is fixed in Tiny 3.5 branch